# Web form with master page design black page

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Picture of the black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee0ED.jpg)

Can anyone tell me why does my web form look like this when I press the view designer in visual studio 2013? It comes out as a black screen. Source code for this page is below.

Search ID:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxFirstName" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxLastName" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Email Address:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxEmailAddress" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Phone Number:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxPhoneNumber" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Address:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAddress" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Postal Code:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxPostalCode" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Country:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxCountry" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        <br />

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your containing `div` tag has `background-color:black`? Based on what you have posted, none of it would cause this behaviour, there must be another element style doing it

Comment: Things to check (Master page Form control and ContentPlaceHolder). Check If you have any external css files, make sure body does  not have the background black.

Comment: Is the page black when you load it in a browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved Thanks. Problem due to css related stuff.